# how can I restart a "do-while" loop after breaking out of a foreach loop?

Tags: perl

I have a small snippet of code from my config script, the idea is the configuration is loaded then each key is checked for the hostname that has been entered. But if a configuration is found to contain the same hostname then it is rejected and displays a warning message that a configruation with that hostname already exists.

The problem is I need the foreach loop that checks for the existance of the hash key to restart the do-while loop so another hostname can be tried or the user can `^C` out of the script.

Here is the snippet;

```
my $host;
do {
    print "Enter the hostname or IP of the ESXi server: ";
    chomp($host = <STDIN>);

    if ($host eq '') {
        print "You must enter a hostname or IP address!\n";
    } elsif ($host ne '') {

        # We need to catch duplicate configurations for we don't do the same work twice
        foreach (keys %config) {
            if ($config{$_}{host} ne $host) {
                last;
            } elsif ($config{$_}{host} eq $host) {
                warn "Configuration for $host already exists!\n";
            }
        }

        if ($ping_obj->ping($host)) {
            $config{$config_tag}{host} = $host;
        } elsif (! $ping_obj->ping($host)) {
            print RED . "Ping test for \'$host\' failed" . RESET . "\n";
        }

        $ping_obj->close();
    }
} while ($config{$config_tag}{host} eq 'undef');
```

This is what the template hash looks like.

```
my %template = (
    host => 'undef',
    port => 'undef',
    login => {
        user => 'undef',
        password => 'undef',
    },
    options => {
        snapshots => "0",
        compress => "0",

        # This is expressed as an array
        exclude => 'undef',
    },
);
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `eq 'undef'`? I hope you are not trying to check if that value is undefined, because that's not what that does.

Comment: I am checking if it is `undef` but the hash where it is checking is hardcoded with the value `undef`.

Comment: No, no, no.. You are either checking if it is `'undef'` (the string), or `undef` as in "not defined". The way you are phrasing it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

If there is ever a use for a [`goto LABEL`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#goto) statement in Perl, this is it.

```
do {
    START:     # could also go right before the "do"
    ...
    if (...) {
        warn "Configuration exists. Start over.\n";
        goto START;
    }
} while (...);
```

Comment: If enclose the label inside the loop, the label will be destroyed when the loop is finished, right?

Comment: @Solignis - not right. The scoping rules for labels are kind of complicated -- see the perldoc for the details -- but it would be possible to `goto START` from either before or after this `do-while` loop. (That would not be a good place to use `goto`)

Comment: `perl -e'do{START:  } while (0);goto START'` on 5.14 prints out `Use of "goto" to jump into a construct is deprecated at -e line 1.` (many times). I fully expect that it will no longer work when 5.18 comes out. In fact, after 5.16 comes out I think I might bring it up on [p5p](http://lists.perl.org/list/perl5-porters.html).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have 3 `elsif`s where a simple `else` would do?
I mean, they only test for the exact opposite of what the associated `if` tested for.

```
if ($host eq '') {
    ...
} elsif ($host ne '') {
    ...
}
```

```
if ($config{$_}{host} ne $host) {
    ...
} elsif ($config{$_}{host} eq $host) {
    ...
}
```

```
if ($ping_obj->ping($host)) {
    ...
} elsif (! $ping_obj->ping($host)) {
    ...
}
```

---

I would use a normal `while` loop, instead of a `do{...}while(...)` loop.

```
do{
  RESTART:
  if(...){
    goto RESTART;
  }
}while(...);
```

vs

```
while(...){
  if(...){
    redo;
  }
}
```

---

In this loop you are only using the keys of `%config` to find the associated value, so why don't you use `values %config` instead.

```
foreach (keys %config) {
    if ($config{$_}{host} ne $host) {
        last;
    } elsif ($config{$_}{host} eq $host) {
        warn "Configuration for $host already exists!\n";
    }
}
```

vs

```
for( values %config ){
  if( $_->{host} ne $host ){
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you're using 5.10.0 or later you could use a [smart match (`~~`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) instead, which would make it clearer what you're testing.

```
my @hosts = map{ $_->{host} } values %config;
if( $host ~~ @hosts ){
  ...
}
```

Comment: %config points to keys not values. `%config=>server##=>host=>$address` server## is the keys I need to pull using the loop. So unless I am very mistaken using `values %config` would do nothing for me.

Comment: @Solignis In the code you included in your question, you never used the keys for anything other than getting the values that were associated with them. If you had, I would have posted something else. `map { $_->{host} } values %config` is the same as `map{ $config{$_}{host} } keys %config`, which is effectively what you were doing.

Comment: Oh I see, so the values of `%config` are `server##`? Right?

Comment: @Solignis Lets say `%config` consisted only of this element `$config{server1}={ host => B }` then `keys %config` would return `server1`, and `values %config` returned `{ host => B }`. Since you were only using the key like this: `$config{$key}{host}`, you didn't really need to know the key, and instead you could do `$value->{host}`.

Comment: I see, well the problem is %config{server1} has more than 1 value, I will post the template hash I use so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @Solignis You still don't see what I mean. You never actually used the key inside the `foreach` loop, so you didn't need it there. That's not to say that you wouldn't need it elsewhere. In fact I assumed you did actually need it somewhere else, otherwise I would have told you to just use an array of IP addresses. If you do end up actually needing it in that loop, (for the `warn` statement maybe) then go ahead and go back to what you had.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are trying to use `do ... while`, when `while` seems more natural.

Some notes:

- You do not need to double check your if-statements. If e.g. `$host eq
  ''` is true, then `$host ne ''` must be false. Per definition.
- If you are not going to use `$host` outside the loop, which I assume
  you are not, since you store it in the hash, you should put `my
  $host` inside the loop, to restrict the scope.

Some tips:

- You can use [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) to restart the loop.
- You can use [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) to do away with the for loop.

---

```
while ($config{$config_tag}{host} eq 'undef') {
    print "Enter the hostname or IP of the ESXi server: ";
    chomp(my $host = <STDIN>);
    if ($host eq '') {
        print "You must enter a hostname or IP address!\n";
        redo;
    } else {
        # We need to catch duplicate configurations 
        my @host_list = map { $_->{host} } values %config 
        if ($host ~~ @host_list) {
            warn "Configuration for $host already exists!\n";
            redo;
        }
    }
    if ($ping_obj->ping($host)) {
        $config{$config_tag}{host} = $host;
    } else {
        print RED . "Ping test for \'$host\' failed" . RESET . "\n";
    }
    $ping_obj->close();
}
```

Comment: `my @host_list = map{ $_->{host} } values %config`

Comment: @BradGilbert Thank you. I guess I was a bit too eager with the delete button when I rewrote the code.